# How to Write a Tensor to PNG Image File?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, image

I am trying to write a tensor with the following properties to a PNG file.

```
type(adv_x) 
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>

adv_x.shape
(1, 600, 800, 3)

tf.rank(adv_x) 
tf.Tensor(4, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

I know how to display the tensor as an image (`plt.imshow(adv_x[0])`), but I want to write it to file so that I end up with an RGB .PNG file that is 600 x 800 pixels.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Pillow](https://python-pillow.org/) library from python:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.fromarray(adv_x[0])
image.save('name.png', format='PNG')
```

There are many other functions in the library which can be used to manipulate images in various ways. Check out this [blog](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-load-and-manipulate-images-for-deep-learning-in-python-with-pil-pillow/) for more.

Comment: Thank for the help. However, when I try it, I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'`

Comment: Try converting the image pixel values to an array first and then use this. It might be due to the reason that the fromarray function only accepts arrays.

Answer (score 7):

Staying within the TF-realm is usually more advisable. In TF 2.0 you can therefore also simply use

`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img('path/to/file/file.png',adv_x[0])`

It uses PIL in the background and gives you all its flexibility, but no additional import or conversion of the tensor is needed.